# Limit of an integral function

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I'm stuck with this exercise:

> Let $f\colon (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\int_{x}^{x+\sin{x}}\frac{dt}{\log(1+t)}.$ Prove that $\lim _{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0.$

All I have found is that $\int_{x}^{x+\sin{x}}\frac{dt}{t}\leq f(x) \; \forall x\geq0$ and $\lim _{x \to \infty} \int_{x}^{x+\sin{x}}\frac{dt}{t}=0$, although I can't find an upper bound for $f(x)$.

Comment: Probably it has to deal with the fact that $f(x)\leq\int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{dt}{\log(1+t)}$, but I'm not able to formalize it...

Comment: That's very close to the solution, but not quite there. Note that $\sin x$ can be negative, and for these $x$, $f(x)$ is negative. But $$\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \int_{x-1}^{x+1} \frac{dt}{\log (1+t)}$$ (for $x > 1$) should take you home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that for all $x > 0$, 
$$
|f(x)| \leq \int_{x-1}^{x+1} \frac{dt}{\log(1+t)} \leq \frac{1}{\log(x)}\int_{x-1}^{x+1} dt
$$
because we integrate in $t \geq x$ and the logarithm is non-decreasing. Hence,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2}{\log(x)} = 0.
$$

Comment: Edit: as pointed out by Daniel Fisher, since $f(x)$ can also take negative values we have to use a bound for $|f(x)|$.